# How to load a CSV into a dictionary (hash)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, dictionary

I'm dealing with (unsorted) CSV-files, where certain columns comprise a *key*, whereas another column is the *value*. Let's say, columns (1, 2, 3, 7) of each row comprise the key, and the 11th column is the row's value.

I'd like to load these into hashes so as to be able to quickly access a key's value. I'm new to NumPy and am most impressed with the speed and ease of use of the `numpy.loadtxt()` -- I can give it exactly the columns I'm interested in and it loads very large CSV-files quickly.

But it loads them into a flat `ndarray` -- not a dictionary. How would I get something hash-like with the similar speed and ease as that of the `loadtxt()`?

Reading a line at a time *in Python* -- such as using the `csv`-package -- is slow. Looping over the `ndarray` to *duplicate* the data into a hash is both slow and wasteful.

Is there some other quick one-liner, perhaps? Or some clever use of the same `loadtxt()`, which will produce a hash (or hash-like) object with $O(log(n))$ lookups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
d = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=None, usecols=[1, 2, 3, 7, 11],
                index_col=[0, 1, 2, 3], sep=' ')[11].to_dict()
```

Some information:

- `header=None`: consider first line as data and not column names
- `usecols=[1, 2, 3, 7, 11]`: select only useful columns
- `index_col=[0, 1, 2, 3]`: define columns 1, 2, 3, 7 as index (key)
- `sep=' '`: it's the default separator of `loadtxt`
- `[11]`: extract the value column
- `.to_dict()`: to convert your `series` as `dict`

Comment: That's Pandas, right? `index_col`? How interesting! Do I even need the `to_dict()` part? Wouldn't I be able to do lookups without it -- having listed the index-columns already? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python has this ability built-in:

```
import csv
read_data =[]
with open('data.txt', 'r') as fin:
  reader = csv.DictReader(sep=' ')
  for line in reader:
    read_data.append([line[1], line[2], line[3], line[7], line[11]])
```

Comment: The `read_data` will then be a list, not a dictionary. I think, I need `read_data[(line[1], line[2], line[3], line[7])] = line[11]`. This'd work, but such line-at-a-time is slower, than `loadtxt`...

Comment: Please edit your question with your performance requirements